# How to set an element so that it uses the remaining height of the parent element whilist having other 2 dynamic elements on it?

Tags: javascript, css

So let me elaborate a little bit more in the title, I have this fixed container that has 3 elements inside of it, all 3 of them should change dynamically since the first and the second one have preference over the third one I need this one to take the rest of the containers space.

I've tried using flexbox but I doesn't seems to have a solution for this particular problem I have, (Or maybe I just don't know how to use it)

And I also tried using JS to get the h1 and p height and then substract it from the container with this little function

```
document.getElementById('DescTitle').clientHeight;
```

but I can't make it work...

```
<div class="Container" id="DescContainer">
    <h1 id="DescTitle">Title</h1>
    <p id="DescParagraph">A longer text</p>
    <div Class="Interior-Container">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.Container {
    height: 100vh;
    color: black;
}

.Container h1 {
    font-size: 8vh;
    margin-left: 3vw;
    margin-right: 3vw;
}

.Container p {
    font-size: 4vh;
    margin-left: 3vw;
    margin-right: 3vw;
}

.Interior-Container {
    background-color: black;  /*I'm only using this for testing porpuses*/
}
```

So pretty much I just want "Interior-Container" to take the rest of the view height that the title and paragraph left and for this solution to work even if you change the window size, cause I'm planning on putting even more dynamic objects based of the size of this last div...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with flex, but therefor you need to change your CSS a bit.
You need to set `diplay: flex;`and `flex-direction: column;` at `.Container` class.
And for the elements inside your container you can use `min-height` if you want to make all elements the same height if the content fits. For the third element in your container you set `flex: 1` to make it flexible.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common

This CSS should do the job if I read your question correctly:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.Container {
    height: 100vh;
    color: black;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.Container h1 {
    background-color: blue;
    min-height: 33%;
}

.Container p {
    background-color: orange;
    min-height: 33%;
}

.Interior-Container {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container" id="DescContainer">
    <h1 id="DescTitle">
        Title<br />
        Title
    </h1>
    <p id="DescParagraph">
        A longer text<br />
        A longer text<br />
        A longer text<br />
        A longer text<br />
        A longer text<br />
    </p>
    <div Class="Interior-Container">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you, need to specify the minimum height for the other 2? the thing is I want their size to be purely determined by the text, but that's why I'm having problems, either way, thanks for the solution!

Comment: Nope, min-height is not needed, if you remove it the elements will shrink to the height of the content. The flexible one will take over the left space then. If this snippet solves your problem please mark it as answered for other ppl running into this problem. thx